# Trailhead ERROR - We can't find an App Page labeled 'Working with Data'

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce-data-mask

Here is my code-
HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-record-form
            object-api-name={objectApiName}
            fields={fields}
            onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
        </lightning-record-form>
    </lightning-card>
    
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import CONTACT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Contact';
import FIRSTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.FirstName';
import LASTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.LastName';
import EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Email';

export default class ContactCreator extends LightningElement {
    objectApiName = CONTACT_OBJECT;
    
    fields = [FIRSTNAME_FIELD, LASTNAME_FIELD, EMAIL_FIELD];
    handleSuccess(event) {
        const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Contact created",
            message: "Record ID: " + event.detail.id,
            variant: "success"
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the rest of the instructions, starting from Step 10 of the [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-and-salesforce-data/use-lightning-data-service-to-work-with-data). If you follow the directions correctly, you will pass the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the instructions of the unit **Use lightning data service to work with data** before starting the challenge.
In these instructions, you will find the creation of the Working With Data app Page.
Please refer to the following link : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/fr/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-and-salesforce-data/use-lightning-data-service-to-work-with-data

Comment: Explain it with valid ref link.

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/fr/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-and-salesforce-data/use-lightning-data-service-to-work-with-data

Answer (score -2):

Huh, this was tricky because the instructions didn't explain what they meant with

> Add the component to the Working with Data page

So I got confused too when I checked meta file and there was no such thing as `lightning__DataPage`. But what they meant with that is that you have to add this new made component to the app what we created at the start of the module and we named it "Working with Data".

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. The community here is generally pretty strict with having answers actually being answers. This, at first blush, reads like a reply rather than an answer. Please [edit] your answer to keep things strictly "to business", as it were. If you think that this is an issue with the wording in trailhead itself, then it would be best to bring this up on trailhead's own help page.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! *Firstly*, almost every single member of SFSE who answers questions is a volunteer - they do not get paid to answer, they just to try to help other people. *Secondly*, if you take time to read more Qs & As on SFSE, you will see that *sfdcfox^ is one of the nicest, most patient, most helpful contributors to SFSE. He epitomizes the idea of the Salesforce "Ohana." *Thirdly* if you would take the time to read about a community before posting, you would see that SFSE tries to help others to help themselves, which exactly what happened.

Comment: Please keep any negative commentary about other members to yourself, as it is off topic and will get flagged.